# Lévy processes in the space of tempered distributions

Tags: stochastic-processes

We know that the brownian motion is dominated by some polynomial function (consequence of the law of the iterated logarithm for instance). Then, one can say that almost surely, a brownian motion is in S' (space of tempered distributions).

My question is now : what is the class of Lévy processes that are, like the brownian motion, in S' ?
Is it possible to have a clear characterization of such processes on the Lévy measure in the Lévy-Khintchine representation ?

Thanks for attention.